# refactor code to avoid N+1 query

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I have my association like this

`models/transcription.rb`

```
class Transcription < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :transcription_status, :class_name => "TranscriptionStatus",
    :inverse_of => :transcriptions


  # Initialize to "new" status if a status isn't already set
  def setup_status
    if transcription_status.nil?  # this method is taking lots of execution time ( N + 1 )
      status = TranscriptionStatus.find_by_state("new")
      if status
        self.transcription_status = status
      end
    end
  end
end
```

`models/transcription_status.rb`

```
class TranscriptionStatus < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :transcriptions, :inverse_of => :transcription_status
end
```

**Problem**

Everytime I call `transcription_status` it is executing `N+1` query. Suggest me the way to refactor this code to prevent `N+1` query limit?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must use `includes` to preload the data:

```
Transscription.includes(:transcription_status)
```

Comment: And read about [`eager-loading-associations`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#eager-loading-associations)